# how to get input from the buttons that I have created in android xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Everyone, I am trying to create a simple pin lock application for whom I have already designed the `buttons` from 1 to 9, now the problem is that I don't know how can I use those buttons to give the input number not the virtual keyboard to pop up. I want user to enter pin through those `buttons`, can anyone help?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: set the click listeners to the buttons, and form the pin code from the buttons clicked

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution :
you can give the tag to your button in XML like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="1" />
```

and then in your java code you can listen to the onClick action  and extract your tag from the button like this :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int input=Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Java file, define a new public method that takes view as parameter.

```
public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
        // do stuff
}
```

> In your XML file, create a new `button`. Name your method as `onClick()`
>   property for the button.

```
<Button 
  android:text="Hello" 
  android:onClick="goButtonClicked"
  android:id="@+id/goButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable keyboard:

Add the two properties below in the XML file of EditText

```
android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Then in the button onClickListener, set the text in EditText:

```
button1.setOnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     editText.setText(editText.getText() + "1")
  }
}
```